# AsyncTask Delays Program Flow / Screen Freezes

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I've got a simple login screen. If you click "Login", a progress bar should appear while we wait for the AsyncTask in the background to check the login credentials.

If I run the code without the AsyncTask in the background, my progress bar appears immediately. However, if I use the AsyncTask, which I set up **after** I make my progress bar appear, the app freezes at the exact moment I click on "Login". Then it waits until the AsyncTask has got its result (`get()` command) and only then it unfreezes, **making my progress bar useless**.

Is this a commonly known issue? How do you solve it?

This is how where I set up the AsyncTask, *after* I show the progress bar.

```
    showProgress(true, "Logging in ...");
    mAuthTask = new InternetConnection();
    String arguments = "email="+mEmail+"&pwd="+mPassword;
    boolean k = mAuthTask.makeConnection("ADDRESS", arguments, getBaseContext());
    String f = mAuthTask.getResult();
```

And this is my AsyncTask. `downloadUrl()` sets up an `HttpURLConnection`. This works, I tested it.

```
    private DownloadData data = new DownloadData();
    public boolean makeConnection(String url, String arguments, Context context) {
        if(isWifi(context) || isMobile(context)) {
            argsString = arguments;
            data.execute(url);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false; //No network available.
        }
    }

    public String getResult() {
        try {
            return data.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return "Error while retrieving data.";
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            return "Error while retrieving data.";
        }
    }

    private class DownloadData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
                try {
                    return downloadUrl(url[0]);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    return "Unable to retrieve data.";
            }
    }
```

Comment: Start your progress dialog in onPreExecute(), dismiss it in onPostExecute, this will work 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like:

```
  @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    Asycdialog.setMessage("Working");
    Asycdialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    Asycdialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    Asycdialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    Asycdialog.setCancelable(false);
    //Dialog Show
    Asycdialog.show();
    super.onPreExecute();
```

And then in onPostExecute:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // hide the dialog

            Asycdialog.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
```

To use the same Async task from Different classes:

```
    class MainActivity{
    new MyTask().execute();
    }



    class DifferentActivity {
      new MyTask().execute();//a new instance
    }


    class MyTask extends AsyncTask{
       public MyTask(Context context){
       }//Pass in context.
    }
```

Pass the context to the constructor, if you want a consistent Progress dialog.

TO publish the progress from doInBackground you can use the following:

```
publishProgress(progress);
Asycdialog.setMax(lines);
Asycdialog.incrementProgressBy(1);
```

Where progress is a string, lines are the max number of items.

Comment: Makes sense. My goal, however, was to outsource AsyncTask in another class (InternetConnection), in order to not being forced to copy that AsyncTask-Internet-Code all over my app. Is this possible or do I have to put that code in every class I'm using the task?

Comment: That is possible, just make sure if you are using "Context" in your Async task, don't garble it. You can also use onProgressUpdate to update your progress in the said dialog. Async Task is the best as far as keeping the code neat and working in a concrete flow.

Comment: But how would I call showProgress from within InternetConnection? What function does super.onPostExecute(result) exactly call?

Comment: Once your do in background process is complete, depending on the return type you have chosen, the same return will be passed to onPostExecute(). super.onPostExecute(result) is the result you get from doInBackground and the result parameter is optional. Depending on whether you return anything from doInBackground.

Comment: Okay, so if I understand that right, I can call MyTask.execute() and MyTask.get() in my main activity without freezing it?
Unfortunately I still don't get how I can use my showProgress function in onPreExecute();

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46436/discussion-between-marco7757-and-astral-projection)

Answer (score 2):

You should not call `get()` it blocks the ui waiting for the result to be returned making asynctask no more asynchronous.

You have

```
 private DownloadData data = new DownloadData();
```

and you have

```
 data.get(); // this why it freezes
```

and

```
  private class DownloadData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get()

You only need

```
  data.execute(url);
```

And if your asynctask is an inner class of activity class you can return result in `doInbackground` and update ui in `onPostExecute`. If not you can use interface as a callback to the activity to return the result.

Answer (score 2):

your issue is related to the fact that you are calling `getResult` from the UI Thread. `getResult` calls `data.get()` that is a blocking operation. That's why you are getting a freeze. Your `UI Thread` is waiting for `get()` to complete and it is unable to draw everything else